# Remote Postgresql Login Deaf

Tags: postgresql, authentication, remote-access

I can't seem to make my workstation postgresql to be seen by a LAN box.  In `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host     all     all      192.168.1.2/24       trust
```

And in `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses='192.168.1.6, 192.168.1.22'
```

I do a port scan on my workstation and still nothing is seen.  No firewall, and port 5900 is viewable for something.  Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Are you trying to connect Pg on port 5900?

Comment: No.   I mentioned 5900 because it was found during a port scan.  Unrelated.

Comment: Is the PostgreSQL server tunning, and can you see the port in `netstat -a` output?

Comment: The server is indeed running, the port is not viewable, not even in `nmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Don't use `locate pg_hba.conf` to assume it's the right config file.  Use the pg server: `SHOW hba_file;` and `SHOW config_file;`.  Devs shouldn't replicate config filenames when deploying with examples or archived defaults.